# Visual Studio doesn't rename class in aspx-file after refactoring "rename"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I rename a class using refactor->rename in Visual Studio 2013. New name is "ProductNew". In popup choose "search in strings". Then VS renames every appearance of the class name in code-behind, but in .aspx doesn't change the old name Product:

```
<%-- Listing.aspx --%>
<asp:Repeater ItemType="SportsStore.Models.Product" SelectMethod="GetProducts" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="item">
                <h3><%# Item.Name %></h3>
                <%# Item.Description %>
                <h4><%# Item.Price.ToString("c") %></h4>
                <button name='add' type='submit' value='<%# Item.ProductID %>'>Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

What do you do for renaming classes in aspx? Thanks.